# How to migrate gitlab rep for another project&

Tags: git, gitlab

Recently we upgrade our hardware and we wanna move repo with history to another gitlab instance. But we met a problem with it. I stacked on step where i must type password for user via i push rep. Maybe i understood it wrong?

For example. I have rep "A" on gitlab.myDomain.com and want to move it to rep "B" (blank rep) on git.myDomain.com

As result we wanna have on rep "B" same rep as "A" with all history and branches so no one need to re-download rep and only they need to do is change URL and fetch rep (our repos are large and some of our team doesn't have good internet connection, so we want to prevent from re-download)

I follow gitlab guide

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin git@git.gamewheelstudio.ru:gamewheelstudio/Atrophia_Animation.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

I already tryied to change git@ to root@ cause i don't have accont with "git" login, but no one of my passwords doesn't much.

Comment: Have you setup ssh keys on your new instance ? `git@` is not your username, it's just the way to use ssh keys.

Comment: The documentation on gitlab says you might want to use backups to move it...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate repository with history you should use mirroring.

you can do it by this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,
GITLAB_NEW_PREFIX=git@gitlab-new.example.com/
GITLAB_OLD_PREFIX=git@gitlab-old.example.com/

REPOS=repo1,repo2,repo3

rm -rf ./*.git

for R in $REPOS;
do 
    git clone --mirror $GITLAB_OLD_PREFIX$R.git
    cd $R.git && git remote set-url origin $GITLAB_NEW_PREFIX$R && git push --mirror
    cd ..
done
```